# Is it correct to infer that use of Default method in interface has made it like an abstract class in Java?

Tags: java, oop, inheritance, interface, abstract-class

Since we have default methods now in an interface,isn't it more like an abstract class with both abstract and non abstract methods ? When it comes to practical use, can we use interface and abstract class interchangeably ? Are there any scenarios where the difference between the two is still relevant ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, there are scenarios where the difference between the two is still relevant.

- Interfaces can't have fields (except static ones).
- Interfaces can't have constructors.
- Interfaces can't have final methods.
- Interfaces can't have non-public methods.

The first point is what really stops you from using an interface like a class. All the others can be worked around (although it might be ugly).

Answer (score 3):

You still can't extend 2 abstract classes, but can implement several interfaces.

Answer (score 0):

Sort of. The key difference is that abstract classes are classes and thus have the advantage that they can encapsulate state and have concrete methods which operate on that state. Interfaces cannot have state, and thus default methods can only operate in terms of other interfaces methods.

Answer (score 0):

I have upvoted the answer by immibis. But personally I think, there few things which makes us decide which one to use, Abstract class or interface. 
Abstract class has some specific features which an interface does not have. Like, interface doesn't allow you to describe any method inside it, where abstract class allows. This feature makes differences.

Please go thorough this post for the details if you want to...

http://javacodingtutorial.blogspot.de/2013/10/interface-vs-abstract-class.html

Comment: I think you have missed the point of the question. With new default methods, it is possible to describe any method inside an interface.